# Why Am I Getting This Error In Threads?

Tags: android, eclipse, multithreading

Why Am I Getting This Error In Threads?

I have used the correct syntax, but it seems there is some error! :(

Here is the Screenshot ==>  http://i.imgur.com/ccPOz.png?1

EDIT: Here's the code:

`

```
package com.pc.threads;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Thread music_2 = new Thread(){
            try{

            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                Intent music_i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NewActivity.class);
            }
        };
    }
```

`

Comment: You should add code, not a screen shot. It's much easier for people.

Comment: Unfortunately Java does not support delegates. You need to define a `Thread` __class__

Comment: @llia G delegates no, but anonymous classes yes. The poster's approach is fine and he is trying to define a class, just anonymously, and also unfortunately with bad syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java, code goes inside methods. When you define (inline) your thread class, you forgot to define a method "run" that wraps your code.

```
Thread t= new Thread() {
    public void run() {
    ///your code goes here
    }
};
```

Comment: Don't forget you also need to call run/start on the thread as well, otherwise it will sit there doing nothing

Comment: Thank You! I missed it! Well, First Time In Android, Without Any Java Experience. :(

Comment: Yep! I know the start() call. Thanks though!